# How to get all values from a javascript array and print in a paragraph tag

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please any assistance will be highly appreciated

```
var array = ["text1", "text2"];
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("printarray").innerHTML = array[i];  // line 1
    Console.log(array[i]);  // line 2
}
```

Line 1 prints only the last text in the array.

Line 2 prints all texts

Why is this so cause I want to print all data in printarray which is a `<p>`

Comment: Use `document.getElementById("printarray").innerHTML += array[i]` - when just using `=` you are overwriting the existing data on each iteration.

Comment: no need for loop .. just `document.getElementById("printarray").innerHTML = array.join('')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you were doing it, the `innerHTML` gets re-written to contain only one array element every time the loop runs.

You could build up a string that contains all of the values within the array, and then set the `innerHTML` to that string. This would override whatever was in that HTML element - replacing it with all of the elements in the array.

```
var array = ["text1", "text2"];
var temp = "";
for(var i= 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   temp += array[i];
}
document.getElementById("printarray").innerHTML = temp;
```

Alternatively, you can ADD each string to the `innerHTML`, which would concatenate every string in array onto whatever is already in the HTML element.

```
var array = ["text1", "text2"];
for(var i= 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   document.getElementById("printarray").innerHTML += array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `+=` to append the new data to `innerHTML` rather than overwriting it each time as you are currently doing with `=`.

```
var array = ["text1", "text2"];
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("printarray").innerHTML += array[i];
}
```

You can also add a line break with `<br>` to put each element on a new line to make things more readable.

```
var array = ["text1", "text2"];
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("printarray").innerHTML += array[i] + "<br>";
}
```